# onErrorResume catches some exceptions only

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-webflux

I'm having some issues catching an exception with onErrorResume, which catches some exception and other doesn't, so I would like to understand better the behaviour.

This is my handler

```
    public Mono<ServerResponse> create(ServerRequest request) {
        return service.createRequest(request).flatMap(c -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(new ActionResponseDto<>(true, c, null)))
                .onErrorResume(ValidationException.class, e -> ServerResponse.badRequest()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(new ActionResponseDto<>(false, e.getObject(), e.getErrors())));
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> getRequests(ServerRequest request) {
        return service.getRequests(request)
                .flatMap(res -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(PaginationUtil.createPaginatedListResponse(res)))
                .onErrorResume(ValidationException.class, e -> ServerResponse.badRequest().bodyValue("error"));
    }
```

And this is my service

```
    public Mono<RequestDto> createRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        // get body
        var requestDto = request.bodyToMono(RequestDto.class);

        // validate and convert to entity
        var entity = requestDto.map(r -> {
            var errors = validator.validate(r);

            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                // has errors
                throw new ValidationException(r, errors);
            }

            // has no errors
            // do stuff
        });

        // save on database and return
        // do stuff
        });
    }

    public Mono<Page<RequestDto>> getRequests(ServerRequest request) {
        try {
            // read query params
            // do stuff
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ValidationException(requestQuery, List.of(new ValidationError("error query params", "message")));
        }

        // get requests from database
        // do stuff
    }
```

So, the point is on the handler.create() method I can catch with no problem the ValidationException which is thrown by service.createRequest(). The client gets a 400 with validation errors.

However, the handler.getRequests() method doesn't catch the same ValidationException which is thrown by the service.getRequests() the same way service.createRequest() does. The client gets a 500.

The following exception is printed on logs on the second case:

```
07-07-2023 09:00:21.713 backup [parallel-2][trace= span=][ERROR] o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler.error - [60e3f148-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/requests?requestDate=07-07-2023"
com.orange.cashsolution.commons.exception.ValidationException: null
    at com.orange.cashsolution.backup.service.impl.RequestServiceImpl.getRequests(RequestServiceImpl.java:98)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/backup/requests?requestDate=07-07-2023" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at com.orange.cashsolution.backup.service.impl.RequestServiceImpl.getRequests(RequestServiceImpl.java:98)
        at com.orange.cashsolution.backup.handler.RequestHandler.getRequests(RequestHandler.java:62)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:61)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleRequestWith(DispatcherHandler.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handle$2(DispatcherHandler.java:154)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
        
...
```

In addition, if in the handler.getRequests() I do the following:

```
return service.getRequests(request)
                .flatMap(res -> ServerResponse.ok()
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .bodyValue(PaginationUtil.createPaginatedListResponse(res)))
                .onErrorResume(e -> ServerResponse.badRequest().bodyValue("error"));
```

It catches other kind of exceptions but never ValidationException.

Can anyone explain to me why in one case I'm catching the exception and not in the other?

Thanks in advance

If I do the following in the service.getRequests()

```
return Mono.error(new ValidationException(requestQuery, List.of(new ValidationError("error query params", "message"))));
```

Instead of throwing the exception, the onErrorResume catches the ValidationException. However I don't have to do that on the other service.

Comment: I think the problem comes to the fact that the error is thrown *on assembly*, not on pipeline execution. In your `getRequests()` *handler*, can you try to *defer* your service call like that :   `return Mono.defer(() -> service.getRequests(request))...`

Comment: @amanin by doing that, the behaviour is the same, the exception isn't catched